# Forward declaration of enums in C (not C++)

Tags: c, enums, enumeration, forward-declaration

Forward declaration of enums in C does not work for me.

I searched the Internet and Stack Overflow, but all of the questions regarding forward declarations of enumerators refer to C++. What do you do for declaring enumerators in C?

Put them at the top of each file (or in a header), so that all functions in the file can access them?

Comment: Typically its in an include, can you show us code to see what the problem you are having is?

Comment: Related: *[Forward declaring an enum in C headers used in C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852169/forward-declaring-an-enum-in-c-headers-used-in-c-code/45856576#45856576)* - *"Forward declaration of enums in C just makes no sense"*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put them in a header so that all files that need them can access the header and use the declarations from it.

When compiled with the options:

```
$ /usr/bin/gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -c enum.c
```

[GCC 4.2.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.2/) (on [Mac OS X 10.7.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Lion) (Lion)) accepts the following code:

```
enum xyz;

struct qqq { enum xyz *p; };

enum xyz { abc, def, ghi, jkl };
```

Add [`-pedantic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-pedantic-1) and it warns:

```
$ /usr/bin/gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c enum.c
enum.c:1: warning: ISO C forbids forward references to ‘enum’ types
enum.c:5: warning: ISO C forbids forward references to ‘enum’ types
```

Thus, you are not supposed to try using forward declarations of enumerated types in C; GCC allows it as an extension when not forced to be pedantic.

Comment: Why exactly ISO C forbids forward references to ‘enum’ types?

Comment: Because until the compiler knows the definition, it can't be sure how big the storage needs to be.  It might be possible to store the values in 1-byte integers (`char`) or it might require 2 or 4 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

You can't "forward-declare" enums because the compiler won't know the size of the enum.  The C standard says " Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. **The choice of type is implementation-deﬁned, but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration**".

Comment: Isn't it more likely that it isn't allowed because it just don't make any cotton-pickin' sense! You can't refer to any of the enum NAMES until you tell the compiler what they are. Of what possible use is an enum that defines no names?

Comment: @luser: You could, just about, make a case that a pointer to an incomplete enum (as in my example code) makes some sort of sense.  But it is pretty tenuous -- your conclusion that they are of essentially no practical use when incomplete is correct.

Comment: @luserdroog you can use an incomplete definition of a struct in header files, so likewise you could have an incomplete definition of an enum backed up by a definition elsewhere, and having that definition included at every point of use of enum values.

Comment: @luserdroog.  My use case was (in a header):
`enum Foo { ... };
enum Bar;
enum Foo bar2foo( Bar bar );`
So we declare function which returns a Foo.  If you want to use it, you'll also need to include the definition of Foo.

Comment: This is not an argument. `typedef struct S S;` works, but `typedef enum E E;` doesn't, despite both having undefined sizes. Actually, forward declarations are just about _not_ knowing the sizes of the involved entities.

Comment: It is not only because of size but because you'll not know the compatible type of the *pointers* and hence the representation  if you use the typedef in pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I came here having the same error, but there is not really much information provided here on the code/error.

My Makefile-flags are: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -std=c17`

In my header I have the following `enum`:

```
typedef enum 
{
  IS_HEAD = 1, 
  IS_VALUE = 2,
  IS_SIDE
} CoinResult;
```

The tutorials [here](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-enumeration) and [there](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumeration-enum-c/)

Would recommend to use something like this:

```
enum CoinResult cr;
cr = IS_SIDE;
```

**This results in the error stated by the OP.**

Solved by using:

```
CoinResult cr = IS_SIDE;
```

Not sure which C-Standard, Code or reference OP was using, but I somewhat agree: Most tutorials and solutions for this relatively simple issue are kinda ambiguous.

Comment: If the variable definition and the subsequent assignment are at file scope, then the error is simply that you can't have random assignments at file scope.  A translation unit consists of a sequence of 'external declarations', which may be function definitions or declarations.  The assignment `cr = IS_SIDE;` is neither a function definition nor a declaration.  The initialized declarations is a declaration (and a definition).  If your definition/assignment combo occurs inside the scope of a function, we need to see an [MCVE] of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

CoinResult isn't an enum; it's a type. If you had

```
enum CoinResult {
    IS_HEAD = 1,
    IS_VALUE = 2,
    IS_SIDE,
};
```

then

```
    enum CoinResult cr;
```

would be correct.

Comment: This is a correct criticism of Qohelet's answer. But it doesn't directly address the original question.

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.