# Forward declaring an enum in C headers used in C++ code

Tags: c++, c

You can't [forward declare an enum in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71416/), but you can in C.

For a C code-base that uses some C++ code, is there a way to use a forward declared enum in C that doesn't cause errors when that header is used in C++ (within an `extern "C" {..}` block)?

Example:

```
extern "C" {
    enum MyEnum;
}
int main() { return 0; }
```

GCC gives the error:

```
error: use of enum ‘MyEnum’ without previous declaration
  enum MyEnum;
       ^~~~~~
```

Clang also fails with:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids forward references to 'enum' types
        enum MyEnum;
```

---

*To give some context, this is a mainly C code-base where a small C++ module happens to include a header for C code. I can do some hack to make C++ ignore the enum, but I would like to know if its possible for C++ to use C headers in this case.*

---

It's been noted the official C specification doesn't support this. However, it seems this is a de facto standard among some of the most widely used compilers: [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection), [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang), and [Microsoft Visual C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B).

Comment: This might be of help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71416/forward-declaring-an-enum-in-c

Comment: @omid-compsci - I saw this (infact linked to this in the question already).

Which answer would help for C headers in C++?

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? Please provide a [mcve] and show the actual error messages

Comment: Added example and error messages.

Comment: sounds like all you need is `enum MyEnum : int` or do you *need* it to to be compile-able as C? If that's the case, then you could use a macro to help you out

Comment: Added some context as note at the bottom, it needs to compile as C, but some ifdef'ing could workaround I suppose.

Comment: What? You cannot forward declare an enumeration in C. Only in C++.

Comment: @storyteller - its working here in C11, afaik it works in older C versions too.

Comment: @ideasman42 - No it doesn't. You are using a compiler extension. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc2dcf239693e2df

Comment: @storyteller ah you're correct of course, it's just supported by gcc/clang/msvc so it's a more or less a de facto standard, noted in question.

Comment: @ideasman42 - Until it's not. And there is no guarantee the interoperability with C++ is the same for every compiler. There is no standard C solution. "De-facto" standards mean nothing when cross compiling.

Answer (score 6):

Forward declaration of enums in C just makes no sense. Enums in C only introduce integral enumeration constants. They don't introduce any types you would want to use. Each enum type is an unspecified integral type, compatible with all other integral types, so there isn't any type safety at all.

```
typedef enum e12 { ONE, TWO } e12;
typedef enum e34 { THREE, FOUR } e34;
int main () {
    e12 one = ONE;
    e34 three = THREE;
    one = three;
    three = ONE;
    return one + three;
}
```

This C program compiles cleanly with GCC on [`-Wall`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall) [`-Wextra`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wextra) [`-pedantic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-pedantic-1) (it won't work as a C++ program of course).

So a useful portable cross-language solution would be

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
   enum MyEnum : int;
#else
   typedef int MyEnum; // 'enum MyEnum' would give no improvement over this
#endif
```

Comment: There is some advantage in using enums over ints - with GCC/Clang there are enum-aware warnings (`-Wenum-compare`, `-Wswitch-enum`), address sanitizer has `-fsanitize=enum` - while not guarantees, they can be used to uncover real errors in the code which you wouldn't detect using regular ints.

Answer (score 5):

You can forward-declare enum in C++ starting from C++11. It's called "opaque declaration" rather than "forward declaration" because technically it results in a bit different effect: the size of the enum is known after its opaque declaration, while with the forward-declared types that's not the case.

However, from the daily perspective it's the same idea: you can just declare your enum and use it further in the code. [From cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum):

> `enum-key attr(optional) nested-name-specifier(optional) identifier enum-base(optional) ;(2) (since C++11)`
>
> 2) Opaque enum declaration: **defines the enumeration type but not its enumerators: after this declaration, the type is a complete type and its size is known**. Note: an explicit specialization declaration of a scoped enumeration member of a class template is the only case where *nested-name-specifier* appears before *identifier* (since C++14)

Comment: @ideasman42 Since header already contains #ifdef __cplusplus it just means that 2 different forward declarations should be present in the header - one inside if using C+ syntaxt - one inside #else using C syntax...

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky there's of course no guarantee that the C++ opaque declaration is compatibe with the quasi-C forward declaration.

Comment: @n.m - agree, This could be a problem during linkage

Answer (score 1):

[This can be done in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1280969/432509), (see @vasiliy-galkin's answer), an example of how this can work for shared C/C++ headers.

C header forward declaring `MyEnum`.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

enum MyEnum
#ifdef __cplusplus
: int
#endif
;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```