# Handling forward-declared enums in C headers used in C++ code

Tags: c++, c, enums

I am having a peculiar problem with forward-declared enums in my application. So, when trying to compile my C++ code, I need to include a couple of include files, where in the enums have been forward-declared. For example, `FwdDeclarations.h`:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//! Forward declaration of the error code enumeration.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef enum EErrorCode ErrorCode_t;
```

This enum is in turn declared in another header file, say, `ActImpl.h`

```
enum EErrorCode
{
    E_NO_ERROR,
    E_SOME_ERROR
}
```

Now to get my code compiling I tried fixing the forward-declared enums based on what was suggested [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852169/forward-declaring-an-enum-in-c-headers-used-in-c-code). So, more like, now  `FwdDeclarations.h` has:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
enum EErrorCode  : int64_t ;
#endif
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//! Forward declaration of the error code enumeration.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef enum EErrorCode ErrorCode_t;
```

This triggers another error `error: underlying type mismatch in enum 'enum EErrorCode'`, which stems from [another issue based on the enum underlying types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766839/c11-enum-forward-causes-underlying-type-mismatch).

Since this a unit test application, I would like to not modify contents of either `FwdDeclarations.h` or `ActImpl.h`. How could I compile my code, with these forward-declared enums?

Comment: `in another header file, say, ActImpl.h` Include that header first.

Comment: forward declaring an `enum` is new to me .. is there a reason you can't/won't just include the header file where it's defined?

Comment: @KamilCuk That indeed worked! Is there any other work around to avoid changing the `FwdDeclarations.h` file?

Comment: @yano This seems to be our API includes. So modifying them is out of scope for now.

Comment: Your question is really about C/C++ interoperability of enums.  See: [Forward declare C enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480217/c-forward-declaration-of-enums).  The syntax seems the same, but the C++ versions have added a lot of machinery behind the scenes.  If you are trying to make them inter-operable you probably need to use limited C++ mechanics.  Probably it is better to create a class that can convert the C enum to C++ behaviours using static methods and having the C enum data member.  The core of the matter is that the size of the enum may change depending on the item count.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852169/forward-declaring-an-enum-in-c-headers-used-in-c-code/45856576#45856576